# Auto delete from SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What can I add to this to make the record delete automatically after the endate has passed? I would like to post to automatically delete from the database after the endate has passed.

```
<?php
require "../login/config.php";  
$host='';
$db = 'db';
$dbuser = 'dbo';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('db');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
$name=$_POST["element_1"];
$stdatemm=$_POST["element_2_1"];
$stdatedd=$_POST["element_2_2"];
$stdateyy=$_POST["element_2_3"];
$endatemm=$_POST["element_3_1"];
$endatedd=$_POST["element_3_2"];
$endateyy=$_POST["element_3_3"];

$stdate=$stdatemm."/".$stdatedd."/".$stdateyy;
$endate=$endatemm."/".$endatedd."/".$endateyy;
$user=$_POST["postuser"];

     $query = "INSERT INTO (fname,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','$stdate','$endate','" . mysql_real_escape_string($staddr) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($addr2) . "','$city','$state','$zip','" . mysql_real_escape_string($fileName) . "','$fileSize','$fileType','" . mysql_real_escape_string($content) . "','$_POST[element_7]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "','$user')";

} } } else  
$query = "INSERT INTO  (fname,stdate,endate,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip,name,size,type,content,link,description,user) VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "','$stdate','$endate','" . mysql_real_escape_string($staddr) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($addr2) . "','$city','$state','$zip',' ','0',' ',' ','$_POST[element_7]','" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc) . "','$user')";

$q2=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'. mysql_error());
if($q2) {
echo ""; } else {
echo "error";
}



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to "automatically delete records".  What you could do however includes:

1. cause all of your queries to disregard rows that have surpassed their end date.
2. Create a scheduled task/job that runs on an interval that removes records that have surpassed their end date
3. Write a trigger to check for outdated records to remove which could fire prior to select, update, and deletes.